# Can't download previous purchases in iTunes

Tags: macos, itunes, mac, icloud

I'm trying to download a specific episode of 24, that I have previously bought and I keep getting an error message that is completely out of place.
I have tried to download many previous purchases and all result in the same error:

[image]

However I am on my computer, and I am connected to Wifi.
I am able to download new purchases as usual, it is only previous purchases.

How can I get around this error which is blantantly incorrect?

Comment: I take it you've tried disconnecting/reconnecting your computer from Wi-Fi, and relaunching iTunes?

Comment: Are you connected to a 3G dongle or a WiFi personal hotspot?

Comment: Yep tried restarting things, still same error. I'm just connected to a normal Wifi network (TimeCapsule is the base station) on a landline ADSL connection

Comment: Have you tried downloading another app (needs to be over 20mb) perhaps a free one to test if it is the product, store error, or a network error on your side

Comment: I have tried downloading other things (that I've not bought before) and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rule out the possibility of a local problem by attempting to download purchases on another authorised device, and refine the diagnosis by trying it both on and off that same wireless network.

Or you could head straight for iTunes support - when I got corrupted characters in my pre-purchased copy of the Steve Jobs biography last year they had a fix to me within two hours. Based on the Q&A so far I think you're going to need to get Apple to look at your account.